# How to add a max date in Data Frame?

Tags: pyspark

I need to add a column, which is the maximum of the date in a  pyspark dataframe

Getting error:  `"TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable"`

```
Part3DF = Part3DF.withColumn('latest_installation_time1', to_date(unix_timestamp(col('transaction_time'),'MM-dd-yyyy').cast("timestamp")))

Part3DF = Part3DF.withColumn('latest_installation_time', (Part3DF.latest_installation_time1).max())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use  `max(Part3DF.latest_installation_time1)` instead. `Part3DF.latest_installation_time1` will return a column which doesn't have `max` function.

Comment: Getting quite unpredictable error: AnalysisException: u"grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`transaction_time`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(max(`latest_installation_time1`) AS `latest_installation_time`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap '`transaction_time`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;
Aggregate [transaction_time#161, aircraft_position#174, aircraft_registration#177, part_number#182, serial_number#183, composite_part_type#303, engine_type#312, engine_model#313, part_group_code#341,

Comment: mind to post some sample data (both input and output) and code? that'll be easier to help. :)